# Voicemail location with two Asterisk servers connected by Follow-me

Tags: asterisk

Here's our current setup:

We have two Asterisk servers in different buildings setup and connected by IAX.  Call them ServerA and ServerB.  We have several DID trunks coming into Server A, where our customer service team is located.  Each user has their own direct-dial number.

Our staff moves between buildings, so some days they are at an office handled by ServerA and some days they are in the office handled by ServerB.  When they changes offices we use the "follow-me" feature to put them in the right office.  We do this by disabling follow-me where they are, and enabling it where they aren't.  by doing this, they have the same extension and only one phone rings.

The problem comes in with Voicemail.  Since all DIDs are coming into ServerA, if they are at ServerA's location all is well.  If they are on ServerB, and you dial a user's direct-dial number, and they do not answer, then the voicemail is left on serverB.  If however, you call our customer support team (on ServerA) and they transfer you to their extension, the phone on ServerB will correctly ring, and when they don't answer, the voicemail will be left on ServerA.  The opposite of how the DIDs work.

The big issue here is that the message waiting light for those on ServerB doesn't blink, since ServerB doesn't have a message and thus the user doesn't know they have a voicemail.

Does anyone know how to make the VoiceMail follow the user to the correct server, regardless of how the call came in?  Or is there a better way to deal with this whole process other than follow me?